# Combining directory files in asp.net with custom-built process

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two directories that contain files. I want to combine all these files into one. **I already know about native minification but I don't want to do that** because I need something custom-built (it's a single-page app and there are several conditions on which files to include into which output based on the type of users and a few other conditions).

Let's say that in folder `MyScripts` I have files `Script1.js, Script2.js .... Script14.js`. I want to use a string builder to open and append these files and then create a consolidated `MyFullScript.js` file that's saved into the `MyScripts` folder. I'm not sure where to look for this, what are some ways of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to do this at build time or runtime?

Comment: Initially at build time but later on I think I'll need modify it so that it'll work at runtime too.

Comment: There are tools that do this for you, such as [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/), that don't minify and will just combine script and javascript files.

Comment: Is there a way to access files in a directory? I don't want to add a dependency to my app.

Comment: What do you mean by "access". Chirpy will generate a combined file on when you make changes to any of your files (that are set to be combined). Then you just link to the combined file. You don't add any dependencies to your app other than a .config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not write a quick function on c# to concatenate everything as so:

```
DirectoryInfo  info = new DirectoryInfo ("c:\\temp"); //Path to JS files
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var item in info.GetFiles("*.js"))
{
    sb.Append(File.ReadAllText(item.FullName));
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Now `sb` has all your scripts concatenated; you can save the string to a new `.js` file if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this may or may not help, came across it when implementing jQuery FileUpload by blu-imp. Anyway provides bundling and minification services as required, seemed quite configurable to me, more so than the native stack anyhow and may provide the granularity you need!

http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/

After re-reading your post I think this may well be of help, especially as the source code is available on code-plex so I figure this may provide 80% of the functionality you need whereby you may have to fork it and add a custom 20% to get it to how you need it!

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking to avoid dependencies and just build something custom that's server-side.

Comment: OK no worries - maybe something like the following. Create a string builder and then iterate through each file in your specified directory calling ReadAllLines http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx on each file within the Append method of stringBuilder. Once each file has been read into the string build use File.WriteAllLines(stringBuilder.ToString()) to a specified file and presto your done http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx